# va_getDriverName() failed with unknown

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

i upgraded to 14.04 and afterwards i got an issue with cpu usage when playing HD.

I checked the vainfo
and this what i got back

```
ibva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I re install the driver 
    **sudo apt-get --reinstall install  i965-va-driver**
but i steel got the same error.

Any thoghts

Answer (score 0):

A speculative answer given the brevity of the question.

A very recent thread in [Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173546) reported the same error.

Therefore two suggestions to try:

1. Remove your xorg.conf file - I'm making the assumption you have one defined.

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
   ```
2. reboot

If this doesnt work, you can revert using:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Suggestion 2:

1. Look at the contents of your xorg.conf file and change the `AccelMethod` value to "glamor"

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```