# Chrome not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

I upgraded to the new LTS Ubuntu 22.04. Since then Google Chrome, when opened, doesn't load any pages and eventually gives the warning about the page becoming unresponsive (even when loading the blank tab!).

I have tried deleting my profile directory, as well as launching in incognito to see if it was a plugin, but both cases resulted in the same behaviour.

I have removed and reinstalled Chrome, as well as restarting my machine a number of times.

I have the following enabled in my ppa list:

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
```

Running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` tells me everything is up to date.

When launching from the command line I get the following error

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
```

Interestingly, Chromium seems to work fine.

I have read the following similar questions, but none of them have provided me with a way forward:

- [Google chrome not opening in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403694/google-chrome-not-opening-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts)
- [va_getDriverName() failed with unknown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455861/va-getdrivername-failed-with-unknown) (though my vainfo returns normal results AFAICT)

Comment: Please fix the wrong info in the title of your question.

Comment: @David oops, done.

Comment: First make sure the Google Chrome repository is enabled - 3rd party repositories are disabled in a release upgrade - and then make sure the system is fully updated.

Comment: I had done both of those things - I tried running `apt upgrade` again today and there is now a long list of things being held back. I'm now trying to remove and reinstall them.

Comment: Chromium is the snap package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Wayland or X11? I've seen this error message occur when libva fails to connect to wayland.

You could try switching to x11, if you are on wayland: On your log in screen, start typing your password, and a settings icon shows in bottom right. There you can select an x11 session.

To further debug, you can also try:

```
$ sudo apt install vainfo
$ vainfo --display wayland
$ vainfo --display x11
```

Comment: This fixed it for me - thanks! Though at least on my machine an X11 session was actually called an Xorg session (googling suggests these are the same thing, but might be worth updating the answer with both names). Also I'm not sure what debug info I would expect to see running those commands?

Comment: Xorg is X11, yes. And as long as vainfo doesn't come back with an error, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04 on a Intel EVO processor with embedded graphics (Iris), I experienced the same issues for months, despite having the most up-to-date packages.

Switching from Wayland to X11 did not help me. I also updated the Mesa drivers to no avail.

This post helped me find the solution: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478267&page=2&p=14111739#post14111739

Chrome now works if I start it with the `--v=1` flag. Once I edited the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file, I had to restart GDM3 for the changes to take effect but I guess a reboot can also do the trick.

I hope it helps others who have been unable to use Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04 for months like myself. Brave browser was a good alternative in the meantime.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tested the .desktop file's `Exec` command with the suggested `--v=1` flag in the terminal and I get the same issue. I tried restarting the gdm3 service using `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`, logged in again, and the same issue occurs. All I see is the interface getting blurry. Sometimes the other apps seems to want to move around, but no Chrome. I also tried switching between Wayland and X11 by editing the `WaylandEnable` field in the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file and restarting to no avail.

Comment: Upgraded Xubuntu to 22.04, using X11, same issue. This solution: `--v=1` works for me, but confused as to why. This is a flag for log verboseness: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/base_switches.cc?q=kV&ss=chromium