# Google chrome won't open after upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

Rebooted multiple times.
Removed all `~/.cache/` `~/.config` `/opt/google/chrome` folders.
Installed latest stable version from Google website.

It launches with with a new tab that's loading forever, I can't access settings or nothing.

If I run it from the terminal, it launches and throws this error:

```bash
dri3 extension not supported
```

I couldn't find a solution for this error, could this be related to the Nvidia/GNOME updated drivers/configs installed after the upgrade?

Comment: Possible solution:  https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15907

Comment: Still not working @Terrance

Comment: That's why it is a possible solution.  Unfortunately, I am not experiencing the same issue as you and my system was upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.  You might be looking at completely removing Google Chrome and reinstalling it cleanly without any extensions installed on it.

Comment: This is so weird, I did that already. Do you have nvidia drivers installed? `nvidia-smi` what's your driver version? I installed 510 and 515, nothing works. @Terrance

Comment: Yep, I sure do.  I use nvidia-driver-510.  However, I think my version of Google Chrome is `Version 106.0.5249.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)` that is the actual installation of the `.deb` package and not from the Ubuntu repositories.  I don't use Chrome all the often as Firefox is my flavor of browser.

Comment: Sorry, here is my NVIDIA driver installed at the moment:  `NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.02`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428842/chrome-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04)